# No results after extending OrganizationUnits

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I've extended abp entity (OrganizationUnit), but after that I didn't get any results from "GetAllListAsync()".

My (new) extended class:

```
public class OrgUnit : OrganizationUnit
{
    [StringLength(64)]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public virtual string KeyName { get; set; }
}
```

I've also added this line in my "DbContext"

```
{
    ...
    public virtual DbSet<OrgUnit> OrgUnits { get; set; }
}
```

DbMigration script:

```
AddColumn("dbo.AbpOrganizationUnits", "KeyName", c => c.String(maxLength: 64));
```

And then, when I trying to get the OrganizationUnits: Count=0!

```
var organizationUnits = await _organizationUnitRepository.GetAllListAsync();
```

ABP version: 3.9.0

Before that change I've used to get 20 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrgUnit`is a new entity type and in your database there's no record saved as `OrgUnit`. The existing records are saved as `OrganizationUnit`.

Comment: you need to migrate existing records... you can update discriminator field.

Comment: Solved after updated _[Discriminator]_ field to **"OrgUnit"**! 
Cheers!